# Why are the Bounding Boxes from Tesseract not aligned on the image text?

Tags: r, ocr, tesseract, bounding-box

I'm using the tesseract R package to recognize text within an image file. However, when plotting the bounding box for a word, the coordinates don't seem to be right.

1. Why is the bounding box for the word "This" not aligned with the text "This" in the image? [image: Output]
2. Is there an easier way to plot all bounding box rectangles on the image?

```
library(tesseract)
library(magick)
library(tidyverse)

text <- tesseract::ocr_data("http://jeroen.github.io/images/testocr.png")
image <- image_read("http://jeroen.github.io/images/testocr.png")

text <- text %>% 
  separate(bbox, c("x1", "y1", "x2", "y2"), ",") %>% 
  mutate(
    x1 = as.numeric(x1),
    y1 = as.numeric(y1),
    x2 = as.numeric(x2),
    y2 = as.numeric(y2)
  )

plot(image)
rect(
  xleft = text$x1[1], 
  ybottom = text$y1[1], 
  xright = text$x2[1], 
  ytop = text$y2[1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply because the x, y co-ordinates of images are counted from the top left, whereas `rect` counts from the bottom left. The image is 480 pixels tall, so we can do:

```r
plot(image)
rect(
  xleft = text$x1[1], 
  ybottom = 480 - text$y1[1], 
  xright = text$x2[1], 
  ytop = 480 - text$y2[1])
```

[image]

Or, to show this generalizes:

```r
plot(image)

rect(
  xleft = text$x1, 
  ybottom = magick::image_info(image)$height - text$y1, 
  xright = text$x2, 
  ytop = magick::image_info(image)$height - text$y2,
  border = sample(128, nrow(text)))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the insights and the sample code!

Comment: Actually @Silvan, `rect` is vectorized already, so the code can be simplified as per my edit.